# User Profile Service Application to sync User Info List with AD

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, active-directory, user-profile-service, user-information-list

Is there any article explaining steps to pull in the AD user data into the user info list?

At the moment the list contains only users who have logged into the SP site. Can I pull in all AD users?

Comment: Can you describe WHY you want info in the User Info List? Generally you sync with the User Profile Service and leave the User Info List alone. I think you don't understand the architecture.

Comment: can you post this an as answer, some hours back I was not aware of the user profile service and now I have set it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you describe WHY you want info in the User Info List? Generally you sync with the User Profile Service and leave the User Info List alone. I think you don't understand the architecture. There are many great guides on the topic, the best by far is Spence Harbar's: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx

It says 2010 but applies to 2013 as well. You can also use direct AD sync in 2013 which may be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

User entry is only added in the User Information List when the user logs into the site. What you can do is to read the user from the AD and then call `SPWeb.EnsureUser`. This will add an entry in the User Info List for the user even though user has not actually logged into the site.

Comment: Nadeem, there appears to be an OOTB sharepoint feature: http://sharepointtweaks.blogspot.ae/2013/10/ad-synchronization-to-sharepoint-user.html which allows to sync with AD check this link. We only have to  configure synchronization connection.. This is new to me.. :) What do you feel?

Comment: Yes User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization, and the User Profile to SharePoint Quick Synchronization. timer jobs help in keeping user profile and the users in the list up to date.

Comment: Are you aware whether user info list is the same as the info contained in the User Profile Service Application? For example, I want to query a particular property then how do I access this, is it via user info list or is there something else for the User Profile service app data ?