# How to access the data from Manage User Profiles?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, user-profile

We are have sync the SP with AD using Active Directory Import for SharePoint 2013.

All the users have been picked up into the Manage User Profiles and new user properties have been added to the profiles.

Is it possible to query this profiles and fetch the properties for loggedin user?

How to do this in:-

1. JavaScript object model? (say on masterpage)
2. Server Object Model? ( say usercontrol on master page)

I tried foll. JS code:-

```
<script>

var personProperties;
// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

function getUserProperties() {

  // Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
  var targetUser = "mydomain\nachiket";

  // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

  var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

  // Get user properties for the target user.
  // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
  // getMyProperties method.
  personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);

  // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
  clientContext.load(personProperties);

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {
alert('success');

alert(personProperties.get_displayName());

}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {

alert(args.get_message());
}

</script>
```

But it doesnt execute the `alert(personProperties.get_displayName());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choice JS or Server OM depends on you. For example if you think that in the future you will need the same code in SP Online, in that case is better write the code in JS.
The main object for that is **PeopleManager**.

This is an example of JS code:

```
var personProperties;
// Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

function getUserProperties() {
  // Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
  var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";

  // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

  // Get user properties for the target user.
  // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
  // getMyProperties method.
  personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);

  // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
  clientContext.load(personProperties);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {
  // Get a property directly from the PersonProperties object.
  var messageText = " \"DisplayName\" property is "
    + personProperties.get_displayName();

  // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
  messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is "
    + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
  $get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
  $get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
}
```

NOTES:

1. Replace the domainName\userName placeholder value before you run the code.
2. If you need to release the same code as an App you have to set the permission for the PeopleManager object

Server side code is simplest:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername"))
{
  var context = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
  var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
  foreach (UserProfile profile in profileManager)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(profile[PropertyConstants.AccountName]);
  }
}
```

If you want get information of an user that is not your current user you need to have the permission to get those information.

Comment: Hello, I donot want to create new user profile. User profiles are already imported from AD. I just want to fetch the relevant property of the loggedin user. Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry my fault. I updated the C# code

Comment: Do you suggest me to use a user control or a javascirpt code in master page for my requirement? Based on retreived property value I want to change the css

Comment: I suggest you to use JS for the future solution but if you don't think to deploy the solution for Sharepoint Online the code behind solution is ok. In this case you should release a web part without UI

Comment: I tried your js script, have updated my question as the JS code isnt giving me the display name. Can you check,

Comment: Also, can you tell me why do you suggest to use webpart instead of usercontrol in masterpage UI?

Comment: The UserControl is ok. I have no idea why the DisplayName is not returning back. Have you debugged your code?

Comment: yes it worked now, thanks can you check this question please: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93873/are-the-sp-js-and-sp-userprofiles-js-preloaded-in-sharepoint