# Are the SP.js and SP.UserProfiles.js preloaded in SharePoint?

Tags: javascript

I am using the javascript object model on the master page to fetch user profile properties.

Do I need to use the foll. script tags for the code to work or are they optional?

```
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" name="SP.js" runat="server"
        ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" name="<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" name="SP.js" runat="server"
    ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />

<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" name="SP.UserProfiles.js" runat="server"
    ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />" runat="server"
        ondemand="false" localizable="false" loadafterui="true" />
```

My code works when I remove them, it also works with them but sometimes it gives 'runtime error'. Just want to know if it is safe to remove them.  [This msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104%28v=office.15%29.aspx) specifies we have to use them on the application page. Can we do away with it on master page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `SP.SOD.executeFunc` supports on demand scripts, there is **no** need to reference SP JavaScript files using `SharePoint:ScriptLink` in master pages.

The following example demonstrates how to initialize `UserProfiles` CSOM in application page  (default master page is used):

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
   // Make sure PeopleManager is available 
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', function() {

      var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

      //...

   });

});
```

### SP.SOD.executeFunc vs SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded

Since [SP.SOD.executeFunc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx) supports on demand scripts, but [SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788%28v=office.14%29.aspx) does not, the following code:

```
   SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {

      var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

      //...

   }, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
```

will not be executed if `SP.UserProfiles.js` has not been loaded.

Comment: OK, so your answer is that: On the master page or any other page (application page) or webpart/user control, there is no need to reference the SP.js and SP.UserProfiles.js only if we use SP.SOD.executeFunc ? Also, what about my code, I have not used Sp.SOD so do I need to reference them?

Comment: I have used : SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

Comment: and there is no SP.js reference.

Comment: Please check the updated answer it is recommended to use SP.SOD.executeFunc instead of SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded in application pages. Regarding SP.SOD namespace, it is a part of common library (init.js) which is loaded with every page in SP.

Comment: OK, thanks, so if we use executeordelay then we have to explicitly specify the script links?. But, what about master page, should I call the script links and use executeasync or executeordelay?

Comment: Also, you say I should not use scriptlink then what do I use script tag?