# SP.ClientContext does't exist

Tags: client-object-model

I have SharePoint site, wherever I open developer tools and type: SP. I don't get the ClientContext as a suggestion, it's not loaded at all in SharePoint. I tried that on SharePoint application pages, on site pages, on different master pages. Any idea what might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SP.Js is not included in the master page. Since SP.SOD.executeFunc
>   supports on demand scripts, there is no need to reference SP
>   JavaScript files using SharePoint:ScriptLink in master pages.
>   Just use the following code and it should show the title of the web. You can run this code in dev tools code window:

```
function readWebTitle() {   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.web = clientContext.get_web();     
    clientContext.load(this.web, 'Title');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    console.log(this.web.get_title())   
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', readWebTitle);
```

See the answer by ***Vadim Gremyachev*** [Are the SP.js and SP.UserProfiles.js preloaded in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93873/are-the-sp-js-and-sp-userprofiles-js-preloaded-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Thank you Nadeem, but if you try to create a team site, and open dev tools, type SP. you'll see ClientContext suggested, but that doesn't happen on my website, which leads me to think that ClientContext will be populated there whether you ask for it or not, which happens in the newly team site you would create.

Comment: Second thing, I am using `sp.sod.executeordelayuntilscriptloaded` but it's not working too. Is it different than SP.SOD.executeFunc?

Comment: But does the above code work?

Comment: Yes, but I don't get it..

Comment: There is a concept of loading scripts on demand in SharePoint. That is a script is not loaded unless it is explicitly called for. `SP.SOD.executeFunc` loads the script in this case sp.js even if it is defined no where and that is why you don't see it in dev tools. However, `sp.sod.executeordelayuntilscriptloaded` needs the script to be present in order to work. It can wait for the script if it hasn't been loaded yet. But script reference needs to be ther.

Comment: But why when I create a team site, and try to verify if SP.ClientContext is there, I can get it without even needing to to SP.SOD.executeFunc? That's what confusing me

Comment: Good question, let me do some research about this.

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford, what out of the box .js files are included in your master page?

Comment: hi Nadeem, these are the files included by default in the master page: core.js, menu.js, callout.js, sharing.js, suitelinks.js

Comment: Yes these are in seattle.master. What about the custom master page using which you don't get the context.

Comment: same references, I am also referencing a custom js file, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your code runs.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

// Create an instance of the current context.
function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    website = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    alert(website.get_url());
}
function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Check this [msdn url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245759.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The ClientContext is not even loaded after the whole page loads. As said in my question, even after the page loads and I open dev tools (F12). ClientContext is not loaded when I type: SP...

Comment: What version of SharePoint and which browser are you using. I have noticed the IE developer tools don't work in SP 2010. However, to works with chrome and SP 2010 and IE and SP 2013

Comment: I am also using SharePoint Seattle master page

Comment: An Update- I verified it's working on Seattle.master, but not working on my custom master page, what would be the issue?

Comment: How do I check that? Isn't it included by default in master pages? I can see the SP object in dev tools, but can't see the ClientContext :S

Comment: I have checked the seattle.master, even sp.js is not loaded in there, only these are loaded: core.js, menu.js, callout.js, sharing.js, suitelinks.js

Answer (score 0):

Try to load 'sp.js' file on back-end code like this:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write(BindScript("~site/Style Library/script/sp.js", true));
            writer.Write(BindScript("~site/Style Library/script/sp.core.js", true));
            writer.Write(BindScript("~site/Style Library/script/SP.Runtime.js", true));          
            base.Render(writer);
        }

private string BindScript(string scriptUrl, bool PickFromSiteCollection)
        {
            if (PickFromSiteCollection)
                scriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url, scriptUrl);
            else
                scriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, scriptUrl);

            return string.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""{0}""></script>", scriptUrl);
        }
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for the suggestion. I already have the SP object in my browser, but it has limited set of properties and methods, the ClientContext is not one of them.