# SharePoint Popup Close validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, popup

I have made a custom popup that shows a aspx page. I want to have a option for the user like: "Never show this popup"..

How can i acchieve this?

Comment: It might be a bit "much", but how about [storing a User Profile property](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/93882/627)?

Comment: Please, specify your SharePoint version.

Comment: Hi thanks for answears, its sharepoint 2013 online

Answer (score 0):

I think, that best way is use cookies.
And every time, before show popup to user, check cookie variable of user choice.

Comment: Isn't localStorage a better option if one is doing client side anyway?

Comment: Cookies have more compatibility. It depends on the version of the platform. For SharePoint 2013 localStorage is more better way, because browsers that works in SharePoint 2013 have good LocalStorage support. But author of question not specify SharePoint version.

Comment: This is true @alexander-ulmaskulov, although I for one consider [IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) to be good enough support