# Can I use the HTML Web Part to Save User Profile Fields?

Tags: sharepoint-online

When a new user visits our community portal for the first time, I want to present them with a form asking them complete some profile fields we need that are used later within the site.  We were thinking of using the HTML Web Part.  Can this web part be connected to their profile and save fields back to it?  IS there a better way to present UI only on the first time a user signs in?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially do that with a Content Editor Web Part if you add some (rather complex) JavaScript to it that writes the properties to the User Profile.

In order to determine if the user was already shown the profile properties dialog, you can save a boolean value into a property under the user profile (such as "Profile Shown", etc.).

If the value for "Profile Shown" is 'false', no dialog. If it's 'true', you show the dialog.

http://sympmarc.com/2014/02/04/spservices-stories-20-modify-user-profile-properties-on-sharepoint-online-2013-using-spservices/

Similar question:
[How can we save data into the User Profile custom property?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93878/how-can-we-save-data-into-the-user-profile-custom-property)